# Custom Post Random Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, random

Hello I have a problem when displaying posts randomly .
The posts are listed almost correctly , I'm doing a condition meta_quey to catch 2 data from the custom post and is really sure pulling content , but the orderby the rand attribute is only changing the first 2 posts of position and I would like to make random all posts does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks for Help!

```
$args2 = array (
'post_type' => 'garotas',
'meta_query' => array(
                 'relation' => 'AND',
                 array(
                   'key' => 'cidade',
                   'value' => 'SL',
                   // 'compare' => 'LIKE'
                 ),
                 array(
                   'key' => 'garotastop',
                   'value' => 1,
                   // 'compare' => 'LIKE'
                 )
             ),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'order'    => 'ASC',
);

$event_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );


// The Query
$the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {


  while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) {
$the_query2->the_post();

$title = get_the_title();
$separator = "-";
$title2 = str_replace(" ", $separator, $title);

$width = 300;
$height = 700;


echo '<li class="col-md-4"><h1 class="title5 conteudoTitulo cor1 title-list"><a href="http://garotasjp.com.br/garotas/'.$title2.'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h1>';

echo "<div class='thumbnail3'>";

$garotastop1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'garotastop1', true );

$imageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src($garotastop1, full);
echo '<a href="http://garotasjp.com.br/garotas/'.tirarAcentos($title2).'"><img class="img-responsive" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" src="'.$imageUrl[0].'"/></a>';

echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";

}


} 
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ( `'order' => 'ASC'` ) from arguments array `$args2`, because this argument will reorder posts in ***ASC***ending.

Simply ( `'orderby' => 'rand'` ) will do the job.

```
$args2 = array (
    'post_type'  => 'garotas',
    'meta_query' => array(
                         'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                         'key' => 'cidade',
                         'value' => 'SL',
                      // 'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                         'key' => 'garotastop',
                         'value' => 1,
                      // 'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
               ),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'rand',

);
```

*I hope it works for you, thanks !*